Mocking ProductCategory findAll fails in Groovy Spock test
I have a class which associates Products with a ProductCategory. It uses a ProductCategoryRepository which is a MongoDB repository. The ProductCategoryRepository has a findAll methods which takes the productIds of the products and finds their corresponding ProductCategory. However when mock the findAll method in the spock test it fails;
Here is the code for the service

    import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    
    @Service
    @Slf4j
    public class ProductsLinkService {
    
        private final ProductCategoryRepository productCategoryRepository;
    
        @Autowired
        public ProductsLinkService(ProductCategoryRepository productCategoryRepository) {
            this.productCategoryRepository = productCategoryRepository;
        }
    
        public List<Product> process(List<Product> products) {
            if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(products)) {
                return new ArrayList<>();
            }
            List<Long> productIds = MappingUtilityFunctions.retrieveIdsForDepartments(products);
            List<ProductCategory> productCategories = productCategoryRepository.findAll(productIds);
            return linkProductsWithCategory(products,productCategories);
        }
    
        private List<Product> linkProductsWithCategory(List<Product> products, List<ProductCategory> productCategories) {
            //...
        }
    }




The ProductCategoryRepository is a simple class with the findAll method

    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import java.util.List;
    
    
    @Repository
    public inteface ProductCategoryRepository extends MongoRepository<ProductCategory, Long> {
    
        @Query(value = "{ '_id' : {'$in' : ?0 } }")
        List<ProductCategory> findAll(List<Long> productIds);
    }





Here is my Spock test for the ProductLinkService

     class ProductsLinkServiceSpec extends Specification {

        ProductCategoryRepository productCategoryRepository = Mock()
        List<Long> productIds =  [11L, 22L, 33L]
        ProductsLinkService productsLinkService

        def setup(){
            productsLinkService = new ProductsLinkService(productCategoryRepository)
        }

        def'Associating products with their product categories should be successful'(){
            given:
             List<Products> products = ....
             List<ProductCategory> productCategories = ...

             // Exception thrown here
             productCategoryRepository.findAll(productIds) >> productCategories
                     
            when:

              def productsWithCategories = productsLinkService.process(products)
              then:
                // assertions
           
        }
    }




I get the following error at the at the point where I do the findAll on the ProductCategoryRepository. Here is the exception:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.call() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: tail(), tail(), wait(), any(), last(), tails()
at com.adx.batch.linking.ProductsLinkServiceSpec.Associating products with their product categories should be successful(ProductsLinkServiceSpec.groovy:25)




Please learn how to ask a question on SO and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Thank you.

Please share the code around line (ProductsLinkServiceSpec.groovy:25)

I did indicate that the error is occurring on the line              productCategoryRepository.findAll(productIds) >> productCategories
The lines won't match because the code for getting the products and product categories was omitted. Line 25  corresponds to the place where findAll is mocked

Let your code talk, do not just talk about the code. This does not qualify as a reproducible example.  Your "..." sections are not helping either. You are not entitled to the volunteers who want to help you filling in the gaps you deliberately leave behind. If it is too much work for you to make your problem reproducible, maybe better do not ask questions here.

This fixed it
         productCategoryRepository.findAll(productIds) >> [productCategories[0], etc. ]


That is not necessary see in Groovy Web Console
